# why is the image icon blank/white when fileupload.saveas

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, file-upload

i use vb.net

i trying to do a file upload, i want to image to save to image folder, however, the image don't know appear in the directory that i indicate

if i click on "show all file", the image appear, but the image icon is blank or white like the image below show

so i click on that image and click on "include it in the project" , however, it shouldnt be the case that i everytime upload an image,  i need to redo that again

**so how should i allow don't appear the white icon and to always appear in the upload folder when i upload a image instead of manually click on the image to include in ?**

this is my code

```
 Protected Sub uploadImage()
    Dim filename As String = FileUploadImg.FileName
    Dim fileType As String = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 4).ToLower()
    If (fileType = ".gif") Or (fileType = ".jpg") Or (fileType = ".png") Then
        FileUploadImg.SaveAs("C:\Users\Jane\Desktop\project\FileUpload\FileUpload\WebRole1\images\" & txtboxName.Text & "_" & FileUploadImg.FileName)
    Else
        MsgBox("failed")

    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
       uploadImage()

        'End If
    End Sub
```

this is the image of how it look like

[image: blank icon]

Answer (score 1):

You have to save posted file to persisted storage on the web server and map files to some URL so they can be accessed from the internet.

In Azure environment local disk (like `c:`) is not persisted (imagine multiple web-roles - how could you serve same image from other instances).

Solution is Azure Blob Storage (you have to [set-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433066.aspx) it in you Azure Management Console) and upload posted file to the Blob Storage Container.

```
// Setup the connection to Windows Azure Storage
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Get and create the container
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("public-images");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

    // Allow blob to be downloaded
    containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
    containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
    blobContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);

// Get the target blob reference
var blobAddressUri = String.Format("{0}{1}", fileName); //create random fileName here
var blob = BlobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobAddressUri);

// Set blob Content-Type
blob.Properties.ContentType = FileUploadImg.PostedFile.ContentType ;

// Upload to the blob storage account
blob.UploadFromStream(FileUploadImg.FileContent);
```

Your file is now available at `blob.Uri`.

Comment: bt i not using blob storage yet...i savin it in the webrole project images folder

Comment: If you are in Azure you have to use blob storage - you just spending time with testing non-azure compatible solution. To answer your question anyway - use Server.MapPath method while savig file - with this method you get url accessable path.

Comment: i didnt have a account so the thing is i just want to upload to the folder in under the project created, my problem is whenever i upload it will not show the images in the folder, however if i click on the "show all file" it show the image but the icon is empty or white, so what wrong? how can i change it?

Comment: User generated content can't be part of project. It shoud be saved to local folder using MapPath (see answer from Eddie). Your image is accessible via relative url (like `images/pi1.png`). Absolute url can be resolved with ResolveUrl. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx

Comment: then why it the image not there? and why is it empty or white icon?

Comment: what the different between mine and his?

Comment: @Mateji i see that link you give, then where should i place it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to designate a directory where your uploads will be placed. For example, if I create a new project in C:\, Website1, the direcotry would be C:\Website1. I'd then create a directory under to store uploads: C:\Website1\uploads and make sure to set permissions to read/write for IIS account. I'd then do:

```
string uploadPath = MapPath( "pictures\\" );
this.fileUpload1.SaveAs( uploadPath + this.fileUpload1.FileName );
```

Once the file is in the upload directory, I can move it anywhere I like.

Comment: isn't it the same as what i did? what do you mean by se permission to read/write for IIS account...but how?